# Usage of "that", "where" and "which"

Tags: which-that, that, where

I'm Turkish. Is the sentence below correct?

**Information**:

- There is an exception. It is used or defined in the module.
- And my field specifies this information.

**Sentence**:

> This field specifies the module **that** the exception is defined or used.

Is using *that* okay there, or should I use *where* or *which* instead?

Comment: If you don't have _in_ at the end, after _used,_ then _where_ is the only relative pronoun you can use, because it means 'place in which'. If you put _in_ at the end, you can use either _that_ or _which_, but not _where_. So _the module that/which the exception is defined or used in_, **or**  _the module where the exception is defined or used_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final clause defines the module you're talking about, so "that" is the proper word to introduce such a so-called restrictive clause.  But there's a problem with your sentence.  Since "that" refers to "module," you should be able to replace the former with the latter:

> the module the exception is defined

But as your first bullet point shows, this doesn't make sense since you're missing the preposition "in."

You may say

> This field specifies the module that the exception is defined or used
>   **in**.

This is slightly awkward because the preposition is stranded far from its object, the module.  So you could rephrase

> This field specifies the module **in** which the exception is defined or
>   used.

Or, if you're willing to personify the module as an actor on its own, taking on the characteristics of the programmer, you could say

> This field specifies the module that defines or uses the exception.